# create directive for datepicker on input click

Tags: angular

> I have a project with lots of components. In most of my components I used date. In this section I used input. I want to create a directive and write a piece of code if I click on the input data, rather than the date icon.

---

```
## Html ##

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input dvOpenDataPiker formControlName="StartDateJalali" [readOnly]="true" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-label dvRequiredField>start date</mat-label>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

```
    ## Directive ##

    import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[dvOpenDataPiker]'
})
export class OpenDataPikerDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input() dvOpenDataPiker;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('_elementRef', this.dvOpenDataPiker);
  }

  @HostListener('onclick', ['$event'])
  onClick(event) {
    this.dvOpenDataPiker.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: @bearnithi plz help me

Comment: what exactly did you try so far? please take a look at the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: @jahller Yes, but I do not know how to use it